# memory layout for packed and unpacked structure

Tags: c, memory, struct

I have 2 structures defined like below.

```
#include<stdint.h>
typedef struct
{
   uint32_t a;
   uint8_t b;
   uint8_t pad[3]; //padding here is added intentionally. 
   uint32_t c;
}A;

typedef struct
{
   uint32_t a;
   uint8_t b;
   uint8_t pad[3];
   uint32_t c;
}__attribute__((__packed__)) B;
```

Are these 2 structs guaranteed to have exactly same memory layout on all the hardware platforms? It can be assumed that the compiler is always gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There could still be padding in the unpacked version of this struct. Even if there is no such implementation today, there could be an architecture in the future where-by all of it's types are most optimal when aligned to offsets evenly divisible by 128, and any of the members in the unpacked version could be followed by between 120 and 96 bits of padding on such a system. A compiler might take advantage of this. Stackoverflow is forever.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be "possibly" but not "guaranteed" since *all* architectures is a very broad range of coverage.  I can envision some systems that have memory architectures whose read/write performance would prefer keeping reads and writes on boundaries larger than uint8_t.

Note that when packed, compilers will use read/write code that is often suboptimal for the particular architecture, but correct with respect to accessing the structure member.

Comment: No. That'd mean `uint8_t` either has padding (which it can't have) or it's the smallest addressable type (which implies that `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour - You've apparently never worked on a fixed point DSP that has CHAR_BIT == 16.  You can still declare uint8_t or int8_t but it is padded when part of an array or structure unless you specify the packed attribute for the structure.

Comment: **7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types**
**1** The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding
bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed
integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
**2** The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N and no
padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of
exactly 24 bits.

Comment: **3** These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Comment: As you can see from the C standard, whichever compiler you were using for your DSP *wasn't* a valid C compiler. That, or you are mistaken.

Comment: There are, indeed, non-compliant compilers in the DSP world.  I admit, however, that the argument is of little value since the OP restricted the compiler to GCC, and presumably stdint.h defined types.

Comment: Non-compliant compilers aren't C compilers. Otherwise you can argue that a Java compiler is a non-compliant C compiler.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Useless sophistry.  They're C compilers in the same sense that spiders are bugs.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "A conforming implementation may have extensions (including
additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly
conforming program." I hereby state that the Java compiler is a C compiler that has an extension that allows it to compile Java, but alters the behaviour of all strictly conforming C programs. How is this violation any different from the violation of an implementation that allows `int8_t` to be 16 bits in width, altering the behaviour of all conforming C programs that rely on it's exact-width quality?